# Add black (or other color) padding when doing vstack (or hstack)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following `filter_complex` to put 2 videos of resolution `320 x 240`, one right next to the other:

```
-filter_complex "[v1][v2]hstack=inputs=2[videoout]"
```

This works great, but now I was wondering how could I do it, so that I could add a small padding between them. Let's say for instance 5 black pixels (even though I would love to be able to customize the color or at least the distance).

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, setup a color filter of the same height, and then add it to the hstack

```
-filter_complex "color=black:5x240[c];[v1][c][v2]hstack=inputs=3:shortest=1[videoout]"
```

See the options for the color filter [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color).

---

Alternate method is

```
-filter_complex "[0]pad=iw+5:ih:color=black[0v];[0v][v2]hstack[videoout]"
```

Comment: I added this filter, and now my video grows endlessly. Before I had a 20 second video, and now I had to interrupt the process, because it grew without limit...

Comment: Now I get a "Option 'shortest' not found"

Comment: `shortest=1` works here. Recheck for typos..etc.

Comment: It does not... ffmpeg version? Mine is 2.8.6

Comment: You need a build from Dec 2015 or later. Use alt method instead.

Comment: The 2nd option "pad" seems to work alright, but just makes the padding on the bottom or the right. How would it be, if I wanted to pad the top or the left side? Or all at the same time?

Comment: The syntax of pad is `W:H:x:y:color`, where W and H set the size of the new canvas, and x,y defines where the original video is placed in the canvas, measured from the top-left. Default for x,y is 0. So, `pad=iw+10:ih+12:4:7` creates a canvas 10 pixels wider and 12 pixels taller than the input and leaves padding of 4 pixels on the left, 6 on the right, 7 on the top and 5 on the bottom. Default color is black.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve this result that may be more relevant to your interests:

**Problem**: Resize videos centering them in the middle of a pre-determined rectangle, letterboxing if needed.

**Answer**: https://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player

The key line from the answer:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" output
```